# How do I disable time limit in TF2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I've looked quite a few places now, and can't seem to find an answer, so I'm turning here.

I often like to mess around on the various TF2 maps (usually Payload maps, such as Upward, Badwater, Barnblitz, etc.) but I always run into an issue - the time limit. It's rather annoying for the map to reset every 5 minutes, and I'd like to be able to extend/disable it.

I tried `mp_timelimit 0` and `mp_timelimit 60`, but neither seemed to change anything.

How can I disable/extend the time limit on TF2 maps?

Comment: This could be map/gametype-dependent. What were you fooling around on?

Comment: @Toomai Good point, adding to the question. Usually Payloads, such as Upward and Badwater

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If all you want to do is screw around on the map, try the following command in console.

`mp_tournament 1; mp_tournament_restart`

For added fun and games, you can bind it to a key like so:
`bind <key> "mp_tournament 1; mp_tournament_restart"`, where `<key>` is the [scripting name](http://tf2wiki.net/wiki/Bindable_keys) for the desired key.

This will enter tournament mode, which will leave the game suspended waiting for a tournament round to begin (and you can just never start that).

Comment: Will the spawn doors open? eg, for blu on dustbowl

Comment: @badp Yep, I'm verifying it in game right now. All the spawn doors are open. It's a sort of "free-for-all" mode.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, this will only work in any game type that supports tournament mode. I believe this is all of them, but could be mistaken.

Comment: The only thing I noticed that some might consider an issue is that all gates throughout the map, with the exception of the blu spawn, are in their initial state (usually closed). However, binding `noclip` to a key easily solves this.

Comment: Several years late commenting on this, but `mp_timelimit` controls the map time limit, not the round time limit. Hence the need for `mp_tournament`.

Answer (score 4):

The `mp_timelimit` command operates on the map timer, which determines how long you have before the server changes maps. You are looking for a way to change the round time, not the map time.

For CTF maps, the round time equals the map time. For other maps the round time is strictly based on how well the two teams are doing: capping a point gives them more time. I know of no way to alter the round timer, as this would easily allow server owners to extend Attack/Defend maps forever to guarantee a BLU win, or stop stalemates from resolving on some PLR maps. If you want to fool around on a map alone, you'll need to keep capping points once time's running out to give yourself more time - and when the map's not symmetrical, one side will win eventually no matter what you do.

You can of course decompile the map and edit the timer, but that's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Are you:

- Sure you're entering the command into the console?
- Sure you're on a server that you have administrative power over?
- Sure that before typing that, you sucessfully typed "sv_cheats 1"?

If none of the above work, then you may want to try making a dedicated server. Dedicated servers are a LOT harder to create, but you have power over most everything on it.

Somebody answered a question similar to this, and received an answer. The answer actually shows how you can give yourself infinite health, and ammo, along with infinite time, whenever you press a button. Try using this person's method if you are still having trouble simply typing it into the console.

(Sorry if some of this seems obvious for you, people sometimes skip these things.)

Answer (score 1):

You can add an unlimited amount of time with `ent_fire team_round_time addtime <number>` Or disable time with `ent_fire team_round_time disable`

Answer (score -2):

Do:

```
mp_timelimit ""
```

It disables the time.